# all form fields are working fine but image is not inserted into the table , its empty and does not show any error as

Tags: php, mysql, forms, web

Here is my code for insertion product. Everything is working fine with db, but the image column stays empty whenever I insert an image /choose file. It also does not have any effect or error when the image is not chosen, but if I do not choose any other field, the table in db stays empty. Its opposite in the case of an image. I've found tutorials on image uploading but they are not working wd my code as well. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
include 'includes/overall/head.php'; 
include 'core/init.php';    
?>

<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>

<?php
include 'includes/aside.php';
?>

<div class="container-form">
    <div  align="center"> 
        <h1>Insert Products</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Register users here-->
    <div class=> 
        <form action="insert_product.php" method="post"      enctype="multipart/form_data">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table" width="700" align="center" border="1">

                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Car Title</strong></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name= "product_title"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Car Category</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <select  name="product_cat">
                                <option>Select Category</option>

                                <?php
                                // SQL query
                                $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM categories  ";
                                // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
                                $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
                                // Loop the recordset $rs
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

                                    // Name of the person
                                    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'] ;
                                    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'] ;
                                    // Create a link to person.php with the id-value in the URL
                                    $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $row['cat_id'] . "'</a>";
                                    // List link
                                    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
                                    //echo "<li>" . $btitle . "</li>";

                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Car Company</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <select  name="product_brand">
                                <option>Select Company</option>

                                <?php
                                // SQL query
                                $brand = "SELECT * FROM brands  ";
                                // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
                                $rs = mysql_query($brand);
                                // Loop the recordset $rs
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

                                    // Name of the person
                                    $brand_id = $row['brand_id'] ;
                                    $brand_title = $row['brand_title'] ;
                                    // Create a link to person.php with the id-value in the URL
                                    $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $row['brand_id'] . "'</a>";
                                    // List link
                                    echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
                                    //echo "<li>" . $btitle . "</li>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Add Image</strong></td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
                            <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Car Rent</strong></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name= "product_price"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Car Description</strong></td>
                        <td><textarea name="product_description"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Car Keyword</strong></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name= "product_keywords"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit" name="insert_product" class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-6">Add Vehicle</button>
                    </td> 
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert_product'])){
    //text data variables
    $product_title=$_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat=$_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand=$_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price=$_POST['product_price'];
    $product_description=$_POST['product_description'];

    $product_status='on';
    $product_keywords=$_POST['product_keywords'];

    //image names: media file or multipart data 



    $image=isset($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //Temp names
    $temp_name1=isset($_FILES['image']['temp_name']);
    //validation:

    if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_price==''OR $product_keywords=='' 
        OR $product_description=='' OR $image='') {
        echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    //here is my upload image to folder code but its not working

    //upload images to folder
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1 , "product_images/$image");
    $query= "INSERT INTO product ( cat_id, brand_id, date, product_title,    image, product_price, product_description, product_status) 
             VALUES ( '$product_cat' , '$product_brand' , NOW() , '$product_title' , '$image' , '$product_price' , '$product_description' , '$product_status')";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    // Loop the recordset $rs
    if($rs) {
        echo 'Successful';
    }
}
?>

<!-------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Don't use capitalize font. Its some thing like slapping on face

Comment: @Abdulla fixed ! can you help with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have serveral errors in the query. First you forgot to add dots between de variables.

```
$query= "INSERT INTO product ( cat_id, brand_id, date, product_title,    image, product_price, product_description, product_status) 
         VALUES ( '.$product_cat.' , '.$product_brand.' , NOW() , '.$product_title.' , '.$image.' , '.$product_price.' , '.$product_description.' , '.$product_status.')";
```

Also you miss a space before the OR between $product_price and $product_keywords

```
OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_price==''OR $product_keywords==''
```

And make sure that the connection with your database is set correctly

EDIT:

The first part is wrong. You dont need to add dots. Otherwise the dots will be displayed in the database. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: connection is fine , i changed my code as u suggested by still image colum is empty !

Comment: where did you define the $image variable?

Comment: Samadani ..its here i think     $Image=isset($_FILES['image']['name']);
do i need to define it smwhere else ? plz guid

Comment: You need to set up 2 things. First turn on your error report with this code above the include `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ` And after the  $Image=isset($_FILES['image']['name']);  do `print_r($Image); exit;` to see what is been printed out

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\admin_area\core\database\connect.php on line 4

Comment: what does the print_r($image) display? Make sure you use the same variable name. because your code has lowercase $image and in the comment you have uppercase $Image

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\admin_area\insert_product.php on line 160

Comment: ah i think i got it. your form enctype needs to be enctype="multipart/form-data" not enctype="multipart/form_data"

Comment: so wts difference between  enctype="multipart/form-data" and enctype="multipart/form_data" ? I test another code with image upload , that works fine . but why i m unable to image upload in this code with other field ?

Comment: multipart/form-data is significantly more complicated but it allows entire files to be included in the data. multipart/form_data does not exists. multipart/form_data will give an error when data is been included. Also try using PDO for the database connection.

Comment: is your problem solved ? or do you have any other errors?

Comment: i solved it by adding this piece of code : if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

  $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
// Read the file
   $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
   $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
   $data = addslashes($data);
   fclose($fp);}